# Как создать отслеживание двух rectangle? JAVA

Tags: java, разработка-игр, awt, 2d

Писал игру на JAVA, ничего не предвещало беды. Как вдруг пришло время создавать точки нанесения урона персонажу (в простонародье - хитбоксы). Я сразу обратился к `java.awt.rectangle`, но тут меня постиг мрак. При попытке первого ректангла пересечь второй (При их пересечении должна была меняться переменная) возникала проблема: Так как противник имел движение туда-обратно, пришлось и ректангл сделать таким же. И вот я радостный ,подхожу персонажем к противнику (Который имеет статичный ректангл, который прикреплён к нему по координатам) и он не доходя - умер(. Почему?

Код:

```
public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
JFrame frame;
private int sco = 0;
private long t = System.nanoTime();
Player player = new Player();
public Main(JFrame frame) {
    t1.start();
    this.frame = frame;
    frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            player.keyPressed(e);
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            player.keyReleased(e);
        }
    });
}
Timer t1 = new Timer(20, this);
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    long tm = System.nanoTime() - t;
    double angle = tm/300000000.0;

    double sn = Math.sin(Math.sin(angle) * 0.3); 
    double cs = Math.cos(Math.cos(angle) * 0.3);
    int xx = (int) (200 * sn + 150);
    int yy = (int) (200 * cs + 150);
    int qwerty = 100;

    Image img = new ImageIcon("resources/testImage.png").getImage();
    Image img1 = new ImageIcon("resources/back.png").getImage();
    Image img3 = new ImageIcon("resources/as.png").getImage();
    Image img4 = new ImageIcon("resources/cheddst.png").getImage();

    g.drawImage(img1, player.getmapX(), player.getmapY(), 6096, 3080, null);
    g.drawImage(img, player.getPlayerX(), player.getPlayerY(), null);
    g.drawImage(img3, player.getBoxX(), player.getBoxY(), null);
    g.drawImage(img4, player.getChestX(), player.getChestY(), null);
    g.drawString("SCORE:" + sco, 10, 20);

    int publicRedrawY = yy + player.getsY();
    Image img6 = new ImageIcon("resources/evil.png").getImage();
    g.drawImage(img6, xx+ player.getmapX() + 800, yy + player.getmapY() + 500,null);
    Image img7 = new ImageIcon("resources/evil.png").getImage();
    g.drawImage(img7, xx+ player.getmapX() + 500,yy + player.getmapY() + 500, null);
    Image img8 = new ImageIcon("resources/GoodCharacterTest.png").getImage();
    g.drawImage(img8, player.getmapX() + 100, player.getmapY() + 900, null);
    Image img9 = new ImageIcon("resources/Mess.png").getImage();
    repaint();
    Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(player.getPlayerX(), player.getPlayerY());
    Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle(player.getmapX() + xx + 500, player.getmapY() + yy  +500);
    if(rec1.contains(rec2)) {
        int z = qwerty -= 10;
    }
    }


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
    player.move();
}
```

}

Comment: Выделите конкретную проблему, этот код невозможно воспроизвести. Однако что означает  создание прямоугольника `new Rectangle(player.getPlayerX(), player.getPlayerY());`? Как он расположен? Почему проверка делается на contains?

Comment: Kromster, new Rectangle(player.getPlayerX(), player.getPlayerY()); - Это положение ректангла в пространстве, где getPlayerX = 350, getPlayerY = 200. А почему проверка проверяется через conteints, потому что если я проверяю соприкосновение при помощи intersects, то ректангл растягивается на весь экран по неизвестной мне причине. Проблема в том, что у меня есть две картинки: img и img6, и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при их соприкосновении менялась переменная. Для этого я обратился к Rectangle, при этом присвоив им такое же положение в пространстве.

Comment: Но Rectangle первой и второй картинки растягивается по непонятной мне причине.

Comment: Так конструктор Rectangle c двумя числовыми параметрами принимает **ширину и высоту**, а начальная точка (0,0). Вот поэтому и растягиваются.